# How to update php 5.4 to 7.0 via CLI in Windows

Tags: php, windows, ssh, command-line-interface, putty

I use this command:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php7/bin:$PATH
```

But still showing:

> PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2017 15:59:08)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>       with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.
>       with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies

I need to fix that, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this through a profile file?

1. you can create a .profile file if it does not exist: `touch ~/.profile`
2. edit the .profile file: `nano ~/.profile`
3. add this code inside the file to choose the desired php version: `export PATH=/opt/php7.0/bin:$PATH`
4. load the .profile file: `source ~/.profile`
5. check the version again: `php -v`

Comment: You might need to do a `hash -r` for the change to take effect. Also try running with an absolute path to verify that it's in the location you added to the search path.